# How to add facebook friends searchbar in website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-comments

I am learning facebook php and javascript sdk. I am trying to create a facebook search friend bar in my app where user types friends name and as user types, the searchbar should display most appropriate result while user is typing. Similar to what facebook search bar does. Is there a social plugin or any other tool available to acieve this task? To achieve this, I tried facebook comments plugin with user_friends permission. When user writes any friends name followed by @ sign on comments field, facebook gives most appropriate result. But I dont know how to get what user wrote on comments. Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

FB introduced API versoining. If you are going to create new app it will use version  v2 and you will not get full friends list from me/friends.

/me/friends returns the user's friends who are also using your app

In v2.0, the friends API endpoint returns the list of a person's friends who are also using your app. In v1.0, the response included all of a person's friends.There are two key use cases where apps need access to non-app friends: tagging and inviting. In v2.0, we've added the Taggable Friends API and the Invitable Friends API to support these flows.After a person has logged in with v2.0 of Facebook Login, calling /v1.0/me/friends and/v2.0/me/friends` will both result in the v2.0 behaviour - both calls will return the set of the person's friends who also use the app.

Read this documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

Answer (score 0):

Either you can create this by yourself (not too much of complex). You have access to the friendlist, so you can get all the friends with `/me/friends`. You can store them (their name/info) into a variable in your application and implement search. This will make your facebook api concepts better.

Or there are many friend selectors plugin/codes that you can integrate in your application. But you'll have to modify them accordingly since you dont want to show a pre-populated list of friends instead you want to implement search.

I've used [mbrevoort's multi-friend selector](https://github.com/mbrevoort/jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector) in my applications.

But if you just want to implement search, implementing on your own would be really easy and less complicated!